# How does Spring's @Autowired work with interfaces that have no implementation?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-data

I am working with [SpringData's Neo4j graph DB hello-worlds example](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-graph-examples/tree/master/hello-worlds) and I ran across the following code in [WorldRepositoriesImpl.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-graph-examples/blob/master/hello-worlds/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/examples/hellograph/WorldRepositoryImpl.java)...

```
@Autowired private WorldRepository worldRepository;
```

Furthermore, [WorldRepository](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-graph-examples/blob/master/hello-worlds/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/examples/hellograph/WorldRepository.java) is defined as...

```
public interface WorldRepository extends MyWorldRepository, 
                                         GraphRepository<World>,
                                         NamedIndexRepository<World> 
{/* no method defined here */}
```

Now the odd part, no class that I can find actually implements `WorldRepository`.So, a few questions...

How is this possible? Where is this documented? Is there a way to make this a bit more explicit (less mysterious)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the code with a debugger attached shows that the `worldRepository` instance wired up by Spring is a proxy object created at runtime.

Looking at the pom.xml and the dependencies included, it looks like the spring-neo4j library bundles in some Aspects that create this implementation class at runtime.

In other words, there is no implementation of this interface declared in the source code - but one is created at runtime with AspectJ and other tools.

[image: IntelliJ screenshot of debugger]

Comment: that's more of the "what" is happening. It still seems rather magical to me and I don't see how it piecemeal constructed a class from three separate interfaces (one of which IS defined in the class). Ideally I would like to see docs explaining this which I haven't found yet and I would like a way to make this more explicit.

Comment: It is rather magical indeed. The key is that it's doing code synthesis (presumably by delegating to other classes/beans/methods that do exist).

Comment: @Andrew, take a look at `NodeGraphRepository` and `org.springframework.data.graph.neo4j.support.relationship.Neo4jRelationshipBacking`, they seem to be doing most of the work. Other than that though, I think you'd have to get the authors of the library to improve their docs if you can't find anything useful in there.